# Using `Node*` as iterator for a list

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Node
{
    int value_;
    Node* next_;

    Node(int value, Node* next = nullptr)
        : value_(value)
        , next_(next)
    {}
};

Node* operator++(Node* node)
{
    node = node->next_;
    return node;
}

int operator*(Node* node)
{
    return node->value_;
}

int main()
{
    Node* first = new Node(10);
    first->next_ = new Node(20);
    first->next_->next_ = new Node(17);

    Node* endIter = nullptr;

    std::cout << std::accumulate(first, endIter, 0) << std::endl;
}
```

In this example I have tried to use `Node*` as iterator for list. I am getting compiler errors

```
  1 main.cpp:15:28: error: Node* operator++(Node*) must have an argument of class or enumerated type
  2  Node* operator++(Node* node)
  3                             ^
  4 main.cpp:21:25: error: int operator*(Node*) must have an argument of class or enumerated type
  5  int operator*(Node* node)
```

Looks like I can't overload `operator++` and `operator*` for pointers.

I have copied this overloads from the book `Stroustrup: The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition) pg 703`.

Can anyone explain what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input to `std::accumulate` must meet the requirements of an [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator).

One of the requirements of an InputIterator is that it support the pre-increment operator.

You can use the pre-increment operator on a `Node*` but it will use the built-in logic to increment the pointer.

```
Node* operator++(Node* node) { ... }
```

is invalid since type of the argument is `Node*`. You can overload `operator++` for `Node` but not `Node*`.

From the C++11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> **13.5 Overloaded operators**
>
> 6 An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and **have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration**.

Comment: But I have overloaded pre-increment for `Node*`

Comment: Ok, Can you explain how Mr. Stroustrup has done it? Here is a link to the book. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipo5pkud6j4vr30/Straustrup4th.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @Ashot, the book uses `double ad[] = {1,2,3,4};
double s1 = accumulate(ad,ad+4,0.0);
double s2 = accumulate(ad,ad+4,0);`. Those are perfectly valid iterators.

Comment: At the top of the page is written `Node∗ operator++(Node∗ p) { return p−>next; }`. It is correct?

Comment: @Ashot, I see it now. I am surprised. It's most likely an error that's been corrected in a later version.

Comment: Unlikely an error, if only Bjarne didn't notice twice that he was passing `Node*` arguments and dereferencing their members by `->`. This example really makes me scratch my head, especially for there are very few mentions of this _error_ on the Internet (actually, googling `"Node∗ operator++(Node∗ p)"` would only give me one meaningful link, and that is to this very question).

Comment: @sunnymoon, I can't explain why the error is not found on the net but it is definitely an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload operators for primitive type or point. So you should write a iterator for `Node`.

```
class iterator {
public:
  iterator(Node *node): _node(node) {}
  iterator operator++() {
    _node = _node->next;
    return *this;
  }
  iterator operator++(int) {
    iterator tmp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
  }
  bool operator == (const iterator &iter) const {
    return _node == iter._node;
  }
  int operator*() {
    return _node->value;
  }
private:
  Node *_node;
};
```